# Auth0js - Login without redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, auth0

I am using Auth0 for authentication.

To integrate it with my app, I use this package: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v9

The signup is very simple and looks like this:

```
auth.signup({ email: 'some-email', password: 'some-password' })
```

The log-in looks like this:

```
auth.login({ email: 'some-email', password: 'some-password' })
```

However, when I call login method, I immediately get redirected to Auth0 page just to confirm...

Is it possible to log-in without doing the redirect? I can't find any information about it in the docs for auth0js...

Comment: did you perhaps find a solution for this ?